# i am trying to using git rebase -i but i am getting a noop error

Tags: git, github, no-op

i have successfully merged my test branch to my master however

when i try to use git rebase -i i get an error noop

and i cant re order any of my commits

[image: this is the kind result i expect]

[image: but instead i get this error]

this is the result from my git log **please ignore the last code line**

[image]

Comment: Please paste all text in the question, rather than linking to pictures.

Comment: i have already founded a solution  with git rebase -i HEAD~4

Answer (score 1):

That's not an *error*, not exactly.  It's just telling you that you have requested the action of copying *no* commits, and then updating your current branch as the result of coping all zero of that empty list of commits.

Remember that `git rebase` works by *copying* commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`.  That is, `git rebase` means:

- Find some set of commits that are not quite good enough for some reason.
- Using that list of commits, navigate to one particular commit, and begin copying.
- After all commits have been copied, move the current branch name so that it points to the last of the copied commits, thereby abandoning any of the not-copied commits that are no longer findable.

Using `-i` turns the list of commits into a series of `pick` commands, and opens your editor on the resulting command-sheet.  Each of those `pick` commands would cherry-pick one original commit, to make the new copy.  In your case, the list is empty, so there are no `pick` commands to execute.  In the past, `git rebase -i` simply failed (aborted) for this case, which was clearly wrong.  Now `git rebase -i` sets up the one `noop` command.  If you delete all the commands that are in the command-sheet, that will abort the rebase.

To make the list non-empty, you'll need to be on a branch that has some commits that are not also on `master`.  Note that in Git, many commits are on *many* branches all at the same time: the job we usually give to `git rebase` is to *move* commits that are on some branch—typically *not* `master`—so that they come after some other commit, often one that *is* on `master`.  That's technically impossible: a commit cannot be changed, altered, or moved in any way, so rebase really works by *copying* the commits, then abandons the original in favor of the new copies that come at the new point:

```
...--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       *--*--*   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
```

becomes:

```
             *--*--*   <-- branch-A (HEAD)
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- master
      \
       *--*--*   [abandoned]
```

where the top row of commits are the copied ones, made by copying the now-abandoned bottom row, so that the new commits come after the last commit that is in `master`.

Before the rebase, there were three commits that were only on `branch-A` and two commits that were only on `master`.  After the rebase, and abandoning the original three commits, there are now three commits that are only on `branch-A` and *no* commits that are only on `master`: `branch-A` contains *all* the commits that `master` contains.